# Apply a custom skin to instance of Stage Video

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using Stage Video and would like to implement video controls to this, like the ones utilised in FLVPlayback component.  I am coming to the conclusion I am going to need to create a custom control bar entirely from scratch, but would like to check if anyone has ideas on this?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, you'll have to create your own controls and link them to properties or methods of `FLVPlayback` such as:

- [`volume`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#volume)
- [`play()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#play%28%29)
- [`pause()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#pause%28%29%29)
- [`seek()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#seek%28%29)